# Generalizing the geometric sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $x$ and $r$ be positive numbers. What is $f_n(x):=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{r^j}{1+xr^j}$ equal to? Clearly, $f_n(0)=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ if $r\neq1$ while $f_n(0)=n$ if $r=1$. But I am not sure if $f_n(x)$ can be written in an explicit form.

Comment: I doubt this works out nicely... I do note, however, that $\int f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}r^{2j}\ln(1+xr^j)$ a possibly easier problem, since adding logarithms might be doable.  And I think you should rename your function $f(n,x,r)$, and this is definitely not some "generalized" geometric sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closed form expression which, unfortunately, involves [the q-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html)

$$f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{r^j}{1+xr^j}=\frac{\psi _r\left(n-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log
   (r)}\right)-\psi _r\left(-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log
   (r)}\right)}{x \log (r)}$$

Comment: Thank you *Claude*, is this **Mathematica** output?

Comment: No ! Another CAS. More precisely an old version of **Maxima**  we customized for our specific needs during years.